# .fit : AttributeError in python3, using imblearn.ensemble and BalancedRandomForestClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, random-forest, imblearn

CODE:

```
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedRandomForestClassifier

bal_forest = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
bal_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hp/27sdwxlj1nqdg1ld2y84c43c0000gn/T/ipykernel_10792/3734698888.py in <module>
      3 
      4 bal_forest = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
----> 5 bal_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/ensemble/_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    433 
    434         # Remap output
--> 435         _, self.n_features_ = X.shape
    436 
    437         y = np.atleast_1d(y)

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: What type of object is `X_train` (run `type(X_train)`) and what is its shape (`X_train.shape`)?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.

I had to !pip install imbalanced-learn==0.9.0
followed by scikit-learn==1.0

There is an issue with the other versions dropping the .fit feature.

I moved from Jupyter Notebook to Google Colaboratory, and the code ran just fine.